# Globally disable function call except for one place

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a rather peculiar situation. A user on my site, who is listed to receive notification e-mails, is not getting his e-mails. After some further investigation, it seems this is caused by the fact that exim (by default) sets the 'envelope-from' to @, which cannot be verified by the user's e-mail provider. That is why I wrote a framework to handle all e-mails some while back (before I knew about this user). This function sets the proper headers and sets the additional -f parameter, so that exim will set the correct e-mail address as the envelope-from address.

However, for reasons completely unknown to me, this user does not seem to be receiving his e-mails generated by this function. I have searched my scripts extensively, and I'm 99.99% sure that there is no other place this user can be receiving his e-mails from, not to mention that there is not even another call to the mail() function anywhere in reach/ automated scripts. I would like to say that I'm a 100% sure about this, but the fact that the user is still receiving poorly constructed e-mails (wrong envelope-from and missing headers) contradicts that somehow. I have written a different error_handler that does extensive logging, so I know the e-mail isn't constructed this way because of some kind of error.

This is why I would like to disable the mail() function globally, so that any calls to it will fail, except for the one place in my mail framework. As the ini setting disable_functions may only be set in php.ini, I can't dynamically change this using ini_set()/ ini_restore().
Thus, my question is, how should I achieve this?

Comment: To my knowledge, this is impossible and would be impractical. You could allow the INI to be overriden, but then anyone who knew about the INI could unrestrict the mail function for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `disable_functions` setting is marked as changeable from [`PHP_INI_ALL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). That means you *can* set it using `ini_set`. You could also add it to your `.htaccess` file.</strike>

You could use [`override_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) to trap any calls to `mail()` and forward them to your own library.

Comment: No, it's not: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php and http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions It can only be set globally in PHP.ini

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. I must have been reading the table skewed. Let me give you a solution that does work (see edited answer)

Comment: That is actually a very smart solution. The kind that tends to slip your attention, it seems...heh (or at least it did with me). I wonder if I can use the override function and disable the function in php.ini. I'm not sure how PHP has this structured, but as disable_functions won't disable user functions, overriding it with a user function should allow for the function to be used. It depends which is checked first, I suppose. I will test and let you know.

Comment: Actually, I am having difficulties installing the required APD PECL module...It gives me a list of calls to a deprecated function (zend_get_parameters_ex). Then, it outputs an error '# make: *** [php_apd.lo] Error 1
# ERROR: `make' failed'. So....seems this weeks keeps throwing eggs in my face.

Comment: There's one more alternative I can think of. Since you're able to build and install PECL extensions, I asume you have admin (root) access on your machine. You could set up php-fcgi instead of mod_php. Then you could run that one site under PHP using a different php.ini file and use the `disable_functions` ini setting. Another option may be to setup xdebug and enable the profiler. Then check the profiler output for calls to `mail()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable mail() function globally and change your mail() call when you need to some class call that doesn't use mail() (it should be possible witch sockets) or just simple call to sendmail/qmail/? with exec/system etc.

You can also call another php script with exec/system/etc. that uses another configuration file. Script example:

```
<?php
if($argc < 4) {
    die('Usage: php this_script.php mail_to mail_subject mail_message [mail_additional_headers]');
}
mail($argv[1],$argv[2],$argv[3],isset($argv[4])?$argv[4]:NULL);
```

Script call example:

```
exec('php  -c path_to_config_file_without_disable_function.ini that_script.php "some_user@domain.com" "some mail subject" "mail body";');
```

Comment: I don't have a dedicated mail server, so I can't call to that to send out the mail and frankly, setting up another httpd in order to run a second PHP setup really doesn't sound like the solution (there would be security issues, external calls, etc....very nasty). Or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding what you mean to say (in which case, please explain further). I suppose it would be an option to disable the php function and then send the mail straight through exim, but as I'm not familiar on how to do this, I would prefer a PHP based solution.

Comment: I updated my post to clear it up a bit. TLDR: you don't need web server to run php script.

Comment: Hmmmm, ahh...yes, that would be an option too. I figured you meant calling the enabled script externally (through like curl()) or, alternatively, simply bypassing the PHP mail function completely and using exec("exim <commands>"); to send the mails. Your option indeed doesn't require a second httpd in any way.